# Spark Cluster On Yarn Resource Manager Memory constraint

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a Spark Cluster with Yarn as resource manager with 4 identical workers each with 16GB RAM. and 4 cores CPU. These are the properties used while creating the cluster

```
--properties yarn:yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=13544 \
--properties yarn:yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb=2048 \
--properties yarn:yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent=0.95 \
--properties spark:spark.driver.memory=1024m \
--properties spark:spark.driver.cores=1 \
```

Yet on the Yarn Scheduler UI it shows
Configured Max Application Master Limit:    25.0

How can this be changed ?

While I submit more applications, the job gets accepted but not started.
`Application is added to the scheduler and is not yet activated. Queue's AM resource limit exceeded.`

I have looked for documentation of both yarn and spark; I have tried these properties:

```
yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.maximum-applications   
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.maximum-capacity   
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.capacity
```

But the limit stays at 25.0. How can this be changed? Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Setting capacity and max capacity might not be adequate. Try adjusting the user-limit factor so that user can leverage on capacity. For example, instead of 1 (default), set it to 2 to allow use of 2x capacity. You can learn more in the official documentation [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html).

Comment: Thanks; I have used the user-limit factor related properties.
Tried these properties in singularity & in combination.
`
--properties yarn:yarn.scheduler.capacity.user-limit-factor=3 \
--properties yarn:yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.user-limit-factor=2 \
--properties yarn:yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.minimum-user-limit-percent=100 \
--properties yarn:yarn.scheduler.capacity.minimum-user-limit-percent=100 \

`

However 'Configured Max Application Master Limit' still stays at 25%. And I am not able to submit applications once the Used AM Resources reaches close to Max AM Resources.